# get started button for fb messenger in dialog flow

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I need some help regarding chatbot development. right now i am doing a project wherein im creating a chatbot using dialogflow and im testing it in FB messenger. one of the modules that i need to accomplish is to put a "get started" button to start a chat and a persistent menu in FB messenger. i've tried to search on how to do it but there's no specific tutorial on how to implement it in dialogflow. i never tried any code so far 'coz i don't know where should i put it. i hope someone out there will help me regarding this matter. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do these using [Postman (free)](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) but first you should have an  **Access Token**

To get your page **Access Token**:

1. Head over to your **Facebook App** that you created for the bot on  [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
2. Go to Messenger --> Settings
   [image]
3. **Access Token** Section
4. Generate an Access Token for your page

**GET STARTED BUTTON**

After you get your **Access Token** Go to **Postman**

1. Send a POST Request to: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=xxxxx`
2. Replace xxxxx with your Access Token previously fetched
3. Go to **Body** and insert the following JSON

`{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"YOU PUT OPTIONAL PAYLOAD HERE"
    }
  ]
}`

[image]

**PERSISTENT MENU**

1. Send a POST Request to: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=xxxxx`
2. Replace xxxxx with your Access Token previously fetched
3. Go to **Body** and insert the following JSON (you can edit as you wish)

   `{
      "persistent_menu":[
         {
            "locale":"default",
            "composer_input_disabled":false,
            "call_to_actions":[
               {
                  "title":"Title 1",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"payload1"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Title 2",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"payload 2"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Title 3",
                  "type":"postback",
                  "payload":"payload 3"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have an error in Postman when trying to set up the  `Get Started ` button. I get : `"message": "(#100) Requires one of the params: get_started, ...`